# Why is my JSON body coming through as 'undefined' for this simple https POST?

Tags: node.js, json, https, azure-functions, http-post

I am trying to create a simple test of one Azure function app calling another. Both are written in Node.js. I can make the request easily with Postman, but for some reason I can't get the JSON body to come through when sending from my function app. When I send the request the receiving function app logs the body as 'undefined'

Here is the code of my calling function app:

```
const https = require('https');

module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');

    var urlHostname = "receiving-app.azurewebsites.net"
    var urlPath = "/api/receiving-app?code=secret"

    var options = {
        hostname: urlHostname,
        port: 443,
        path: urlPath,
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        }
    };

    const request = https.request(options, (response) => {
        context.log(`statusCode: ${response.statusCode}`)

        response.on('data', (data) => {
            context.log('response data: ${data}')
        })
    })

    request.on('error', (error) => {
        context.log(error)
    })

    const payload = {
        name: "test"
    }
    context.log('payload: ' + JSON.stringify(payload))

    request.write(JSON.stringify(payload))
    request.end()


    context.res = {
        // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
        body: "done"
    };
}
```

Here is the receiving function app:

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');
    context.log(context.req);
    context.log(req.body);

    context.res = {
        // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
        body: "Hello "
    };
}
```

edit:

modified my calling function to this:

```
const https = require('https');

module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');

    var urlHostname = "xxxxx.azurewebsites.net"
    var urlPath = "/api/xxxxx?code=xxxxxxxxx"

    var options = {
        hostname: urlHostname,
        port: 443,
        path: urlPath,
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        }
    };

    var request = https.request(options, function (res) {
        console.log("STATUS: " + res.statusCode);
        console.log("HEADERS: " + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
        res.setEncoding("utf8");
        res.on("data", function (chunk) {
          console.log("BODY: " + chunk);
        });
      });
    
    request.on("error", function (e) {
        console.log("Problem with request: " + e);
    });

    // write data to request body
    var payload = {
        id: 12345,
        value: "abc-def-ghi",
    };

    request.write(JSON.stringify(payload));
    request.end();

    context.res = {

        // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
        body: "done"
    };
}
```

Now I'm receiving this 401 error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ExpiredAuthenticationToken",
    "message": "The access token expiry UTC time '12/26/2022 6:39:13 PM' is earlier than current UTC time '12/26/2022 6:44:34 PM'."
  }
}
```

Comment: What block(s) should this replace in my code?

Comment: also, you'll need to use backticks here: `context.log(\`response data: ${data}\`)`, this is some ancient js code... can you might be able to save yourself some headaches in the future by using at least es6

Comment: I posted my modified code above. The body is still coming in as undefined. Did I misunderstand your suggestion?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/red-cache-jb75fj?file=%2Findex.js&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A22%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A4%2C%22startColumn%22%3A22%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A4%7D%5D Please have a look at this sample

Comment: Are the API endpoints in the question correct?

Comment: They seem to be correct as the receiving function app is processing the request, I can see it in the logs. It just isn't getting the body

Comment: I just modified the code based on the sample, and now I'm getting a 401 error. Posted in the main question above

Comment: It's getting the body and prints in the console, https://i.imgur.com/GD7UvMp.png

Comment: Based on the updated question, you should add some auth token in the request headers

Comment: I'm not sure why I would need an auth token all of a sudden. I can make a successful call to the same url in postman by simply pasting in the url, selecting post, adding the application/json content-type header, and adding some json to the raw body. All I'm trying to do is mimic that in this function app